# Ansible: looped variable referenced in another loop

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to reference another variable in loop1 to be used in loop2?

Here is my dummy playbook which doesn't work:

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - br:
      - dir1
      - dir2
    - folders:
      - /folder1/"{{ item.1 }}"/sub1
      - /folder1/"{{ item.1 }}"/sub2
    tasks:
    - name:
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ folders }}"
        - "{{ br }}"
```

The output i'm trying to achieve is:

```
/folder1/dir1/sub1
/folder1/dir1/sub2
/folder1/dir2/sub1
/folder1/dir2/sub2


Thank you. Appreciate your response.
```

Comment: I only see a single loop here (the `with_nested` loop on your `debug`  task).

Comment: @larsks I actually also tried `loop` and a few other `with_X`, but I can't seem to get the result i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you don't have requirements on the variables to use, you just want to achieve the provided list of folders in an efficient way (with a loop). You could use these vars to get the output you want using the `with_nested` loop:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    - folders:
      - dir1
      - dir2
    - subfolders:
      - sub1
      - sub2
  tasks:
  - name:
    debug:
      msg: "/folder1/{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }}"
    with_nested:
      - "{{ folders }}"
      - "{{ subfolders }}"
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the cross product of your two lists, so you could write:

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - br:
      - dir1
      - dir2
    - folders:
      - /folder1/%s/sub1
      - /folder1/%s/sub2
  tasks:
    - name:
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.1 % item.0 }}"
      loop: "{{ br|product(folders) }}"
```

This uses Python-style string formatting (e.g. `"Hello %s" % "world"`) to substitute the desired valued into the output.

This produces as output:

```
PLAY [test] ********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir1', '/folder1/%s/sub1']) => {
    "msg": "/folder1/dir1/sub1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir1', '/folder1/%s/sub2']) => {
    "msg": "/folder1/dir1/sub2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir2', '/folder1/%s/sub1']) => {
    "msg": "/folder1/dir2/sub1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['dir2', '/folder1/%s/sub2']) => {
    "msg": "/folder1/dir2/sub2"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you @larsks. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jinja to create the structure, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    root:
      - folder1
    br:
      - dir1
      - dir2
    sub:
      - sub1
      - sub2
    _folders: |-
      {% for r in root %}
      {% for b in br %}
      {% for s in sub %}
      - /{{ r }}/{{ b }}/{{ s }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    folders: "{{ _folders|from_yaml }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: folders
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  folders:
  - /folder1/dir1/sub1
  - /folder1/dir1/sub2
  - /folder1/dir2/sub1
  - /folder1/dir2/sub2
```

You can hide it in a file and separate the dynamic data from the code, e.g. the play below gives the same result

```yaml
shell> cat my_vars.yml
root:
  - folder1
br:
  - dir1
  - dir2
sub:
  - sub1
  - sub2
_folders: |-
  {% for r in root %}
  {% for b in br %}
  {% for s in sub %}
  - /{{ r }}/{{ b }}/{{ s }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
folders: "{{ _folders|from_yaml }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - my_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: folders
```